# $z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5=n$ satisfing $i\not\mid z_i$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In multiple choice test had a problem:
How many positive integer solutions of
$z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5=n$ satisfing $i\not\mid z_i$

Answer:

A. $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^n \left\lfloor\dfrac{{k\choose 2}}{5}\right\rfloor$

B. $\left\lfloor\dfrac{(n-1)(n-2)(n+3)}{30}\right\rfloor$

———

My solution:

We have general function
$$\begin {align*}
 G(x)&=\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}-(1+x^2+x^4+…)\right) \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}-(1+x^3+x^6+…)\right)\\
&\quad  \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}-(1+x^4+x^8+…)\right) \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}-(1+x^5+x^{10}+…)\right)\\
&=  \frac {x^4}{(1-x)^4(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)}
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin {align*}
 G(x)&=\frac { x^4}{(x-1)^4(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)}\\
&=\frac{x+x^2-x^3-x^4}{5(1-x^5)}+\frac{1}{5(1-x)}\\
&\quad -\frac{2}{5(1-x)^3}+\frac{1}{5(1-x)^4}\\
\Longrightarrow \left [ x^n \right ]G(x)&=\left ( \left [x^{n-1}  \right ]+\left [x^{n-2}  \right ]-\left [x^{n-3}  \right ]-\left [x^{n-4}  \right ] \right )\frac {1}{5}\sum_{k\geq 0}x^{5k}\\
&\quad +\frac {1}{5}-\frac {2}{5}\binom{n+2}{2}+\frac {1}{5}\binom{n+3}{3}
\end {align*} $$

Number of solutions  :
$$\left [ x^n \right ]G(x)= \left \{ \begin{matrix} & 
\frac {1}{5}-\frac {2}{5}\binom{n+2}{2}+\frac {1}{5}\binom{n+3}{3}  &&\text{if $n \equiv 0\!\! \pmod{5}$ }\\ & \frac {2}{5}-\frac {2}{5}\binom{n+2}{2}+\frac {1}{5}\binom{n+3}{3}&&\text{if $n \equiv 1,2\!\! \pmod{5}$ } \\
&-\frac {2}{5}\binom{n+2}{2}+\frac {1}{5}\binom{n+3}{3}  &&\text{if $n \equiv 3,4\!\! \pmod{5}$ }
\end{matrix}\right.$$
My choice B. answer
but answer exacted is A. WHY?

Comment: Have you tried actually computing some numbers?  It might be that your answer is actually ***A*** in disguise.

Comment: @awkward I think that OP see that $$[x^n]G(x)=[x^n]\frac{x^4}{(1-x)^3(1-x^5)}$$ and its expansion is stated by choice A, but OP want to see how the formula derived

Comment: By doing the same thing when expanding the number of variables to $z_6$, the result is $\left\lfloor\left(\dfrac{n^2-10}{12}\right)^2\right\rfloor$. However, I still cannot understand how formula A is constructed.

Comment: @Not a Salmon Fish $$\begin{align*}G(x)&=\dfrac{x^4}{(1-x)^3(1-x^5)}\\ &=\dfrac 12 \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)’’ \left(-\dfrac 15\right)(\ln(1-x^5))’ \\&=\sum_{j\ge 0} {j+2\choose 2} x^j \sum_{k\ge 1} x^{5k-1}\end{align*}$$
Therefor:
$\displaystyle [x^n]G(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\right\rfloor} {n+3-5k\choose 2}$ but still $\ne A$

Comment: They are equal at least for first few numbers from wolfram alpha. https://shorturl.at/byELO and  https://shorturl.at/xySX5

Answer (score 2):

You've already got
$$[x^n]G(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor}\binom{n-5m+3}{2}$$

This answer proves the following two claims :

**Claim 1** :
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor}\binom{n-5m+3}{2}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{\binom k2}{5}\right\rfloor$$

**Claim 2** :
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor}\binom{n-5m+3}{2}=\left\lfloor\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n+3)}{30}\right\rfloor$$

---

**Claim 1** :
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor}\binom{n-5m+3}{2}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{\binom k2}{5}\right\rfloor$$

*Proof* :

Let $k:=n-5m+3$. Then,
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor}\binom{n-5m+3}{2}=\sum_{k\in\{n-5\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor+3,n-5\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor+8,\cdots, n-2\}}\binom k2
=\sum_{k\in\{n-2-5(\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor-1),n-2-5(\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor-2),\cdots, n-2\}}\binom k2\tag1$$

For any integer $s$, we have
$$\binom{n-2-5s}2=\left\lfloor\frac 15\binom{n-5s}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac 15\binom{n-1-5s}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac 15\binom{n-2-5s}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac 15\binom{n-3-5s}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac 15\binom{n-4-5s}{2}\right\rfloor\tag2$$

A proof of $(2)$ is as follows :

Let $n=5t+r$ where $t\in\mathbb Z$ and $r=0,1,2,3,4$.

Then, the RHS of $(2)$ can be written as
$$-5s(5t+r)+\frac{25s(s+1)}{2}+5tr+\frac{25t(t-1)}{2}+F(r)$$
where $$F(r)=\left\lfloor \frac{r(r-1)}{10}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{(r-2)(r-1)}{10}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(r-2)(r-3)}{10}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(r-3)(r-4)}{10}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(r-4)(r-5)}{10}\right\rfloor$$

So, $(2)$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{(r-2)(r-3)}{2}=F(r)\tag3$$
Considering $r=0,1,2,3$ and $4$, we can see that $(3)$ holds. So, $(2)$ holds.

Therefore, from $(2)$, we get
$$(1)=\sum_{k=n-4-5(\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor-1)}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{\binom k2}{5}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{\binom k2}{5}\right\rfloor.\blacksquare$$

---

**Claim 2** :
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor}\binom{n-5m+3}{2}=\left\lfloor\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n+3)}{30}\right\rfloor$$

*Proof* :

Let $n=5t+r$ where $t\in\mathbb Z$ and $r=0,1,2,3,4$.

- For $0\le r\le 3$, we have $$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n+3)}{30}=t(4t^2+2rt-1)+\underbrace{\frac{tr(t+r)}{2}}_{\text{integer}} + \underbrace{\frac{(t-1)t(t+1)}{6}}_{\text{integer}} +\underbrace{\frac{(r - 1) (r - 2) (r + 3)}{30}}_{\lt 1}$$ Since $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor=t$, we get
  $$\text{RHS}-\text{LHS}=t(4t^2+2rt-1)+\frac{tr(t+r)}{2} + \frac{(t-1)t(t+1)}{6} -\frac 16 t (3 r^2 + 15 r t + 25 t^2 - 7)=0$$
- For $r=4$, we have $$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n+3)}{30}=4t^3+10t^2+7t+1+\underbrace{\frac{(t-1)t(t+1)}{6}}_{\text{integer}}+\frac 25 $$ Since $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor=t+1$, we get
  $$\text{RHS}-\text{LHS}=4t^3+10t^2+7t+1+\frac{(t-1)t(t+1)}{6}-\frac 16 (25 t^3 + 60 t^2 + 41 t + 6)=0$$

Therefore, claim 2 follows.$\ \blacksquare$